# Regular expression to get url parameter

Tags: regex

Im trying to do a regular expression to get something like this:

The string can be

```
/dira/dirb/dirc/dirn?e=0?e=0?e=3?e=0?e
```

or

```
/dira/dirb/dirc/dire/dirw/dirw/diw?e=?e=?e=3?e=?e
```

(The number of subdirs is variable)

I need to capture `/dira/dirb/dirc/dirn?e=0` if the first e have value or `/dira/dirb/dirc/dirn?e=` if the first e dont have value:

I have this:

```
(.+)(\?e=\d?)
```

Im try with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but i dont find nothing.

Comment: Seems to find a match for me: http://regexr.com?32v7h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex: `(/dir?.)+(\?e=\d*)+\?e`

Or, if the `diw` at the end of the second example isn't just a mistake in your post, then your  regex should be `(/dir.)+(\?e=\d*)+\?e`.

Comment: I need only capture

/dira/dirb/dirc/dire/dirw/dirw/diw?e= (To the first e parameter, with value if have)